# JButton not re-enabling when selecting a row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

I'm trying to set a button in enabled(false) when I create it, and when I select any row on the Jtable, that button goes enabled(true).

Logic is pretty simple here, but for some reason, it doesn't quite work, the button never gets into enabled(true).

```
    JButton btnIniciarReparacin = new JButton("INICIAR REPARACI\u00D3N");
    
    btnIniciarReparacin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tiempoStart = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
            btnIniciarReparacin.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
    btnIniciarReparacin.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnIniciarReparacin.setBackground(new Color(231, 111, 81));
    btnIniciarReparacin.setBounds(129, 625, 254, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnIniciarReparacin);
    
    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
    //Comprobamos si hemos cogido algo de la tabla y si los botones están encendidos
    if (table.isRowSelected(row)) {
        btnIniciarReparacin.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        btnIniciarReparacin.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swing GUI's work by your adding listeners to events and then responding to state changes within the listener.

You appear to be checking the row selection state in code where you create your components, and that will never work since it only checks the state once, and before the user has had a chance to make a selection. Instead, you need to use a listener on your JTable, more specifically a ListSelectionListener that you add to the JTable's selection model that you get via `table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(...)`

Also note that this:

```
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
if (table.isRowSelected(row)) {
    btnIniciarReparacin.setEnabled(true);
} else {
    btnIniciarReparacin.setEnabled(false);
}
```

can be shortened to:

```
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
btnIniciarReparacin.setEnabled(table.isRowSelected(row));
```

e.g. something like:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        btnIniciarReparacin.setEnabled(table.isRowSelected(row));
    }
});
```

For example, if the button deletes a row:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test01 extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
    private DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(COLUMNS, 0);
    private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    private JButton deleteRowButton = new JButton("Delete Row");
    
    public Test01() {
        int tableRows = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableRows; i++) {
            Integer[] row = new Integer[COLUMNS.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                row[j] = (int) (100 * Math.random());
            }
            tableModel.addRow(row);
        }
        
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                deleteRowButton.setEnabled(table.isRowSelected(row));
            }
        });
        
        deleteRowButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            int row = table.getSelectedRow();
            tableModel.removeRow(row);
        });
        deleteRowButton.setEnabled(false);
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(deleteRowButton);
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Test01 mainPanel = new Test01();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test01");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: And where do you suggest I use it? After creating the table? Also, do I use "table" into the addListSelectionListener()?

Comment: You add the listener to the table's selection model when and where you create your table. For an example, see edit to answer above.  Please ask if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Cpt-Proxy: see above comment. Also (again) please comment if something isn't clear or doesn't make sense. The posted code is compilable and runnable on its own, so please check it out.

Comment: Also note that table.isRowSelected(table.getSelectedRow()) will ways be true. The better check would be if table.grrSelectedRow() non negative.

Comment: @weisj: not so. If -1 one is returned then the boolean is false.